# Git source code pull

Tags: git

How do I get the source code form Git?
I am looking at the main page for for the Tails operation system

https://git-tails.immerda.ch/liveusb-creator/?h=master

but all I can click on is patches and upgrades. How do I get the latest source for the whole program?

Comment: Look at the bottom of that page, where it says "Clone". Then use `git clone <url>`. Or if you want to browse the code in the browser, click on the tab "tree". Not sure what you want exactly. Stack Overflow is not a place to help you figure out how to use a website.

Comment: @FelixKling thanks, but I am figuring it out know and there is no mention of how get the source in git's own manual that's why I am asking it here (I still can't find the source, not even in the 'tree')

Comment: ? If you click the tree tab, you see a list of files and folders. That's the code. Isn't that what you want?

Comment: @FelixKling it just seems too short, it's about 5000 lines altogether

Answer (score 1):

Try this command to clone from git

```
git clone https://git-tails.immerda.ch/liveusb-creator
```

Comment: thanks, but is there a way I can access it without downloading git?

Comment: Use this link to navigate through directories of the code. https://git-tails.immerda.ch/liveusb-creator/tree/